# How to neo4j to Tigergraph (file is in graphml format)

Tags: neo4j-apoc, graphml, tigergraph

i'm trying to migrate the schema from neo4j to tigergraph where i exported the data from neo4j in graphml format and trying to parse the file and create schema in tigergraph.
Do let me know if there is any other way than manually creating one.

Answer (score 0):

This project open-source project is a bit old, but I believe could help you https://github.com/TigerGraph-DevLabs/GraphML-TG It covers how to import the graphml schema and data into TigerGraph DB.